# Get the size of the array by reference

Tags: c++

I created a vector of pointers to an array

```
vector<PxVec3*> gConvexMeshVertexesArrays;
```

I added a link to the array with elements

```
static PxVec3 convexVerts[] = {
    PxVec3(-0.000000, 1.295039, -5.117647),
    PxVec3(-9.881939, 10.235294, 5.235294),
    PxVec3(-10.117647, 10.235294, 5.235294)
}
```

Then I try to get the size of this array

```
cout << "in = " << sizeof(convexVerts) / sizeof(PxVec3) << endl; //ok
gConvexMeshVertexesArrays.push_back(convexVerts);
cout << "in2 = " << sizeof(*(gConvexMeshVertexesArrays.back())) / sizeof(PxVec3) << endl; //wrong!
```

How can I make the second option work correctly? After all, back() returns a reference to the pointer and the size of the array I can't get from the reference.

Thanks.

Comment: A `PxVec*` points to one `PxVec` and `sizeof` tells you that.  Storing only the address of the first element in the array, there is no way to tell what other elements might be in later memory locations.  You would have to store something else in the vector in order to have additional information

Comment: Why don't you just use a vector of vector instead? Or vector of std::array if you know the size at compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a vector of pointers to an array
>
> ```
> vector<PxVec3*> gConvexMeshVertexesArrays;
> ```

You've created a vector of pointers to `PxVec3`, which I assume is not an array. Those pointed `PxVec3` objects may be elements of an array though.

> ```
> cout << "in2 = " << sizeof(*(gConvexMeshVertexesArrays.back())) / sizeof(PxVec3) << endl; //wrong!
> ```
>
> How can I make the second option work correctly?

This would work, if you actually did have a vector of pointers to an array:

```
std::vector<PxVec3(*)[3]> gConvexMeshVertexesArrays;
```

This way, indirecting through the pointer to array, you get an lvalue reference to the array itself, and you can get the size of that array the same way as you'd get it from the array directly as you are attempting here.

---

If you instead have a pointer to an element of an array, as you do in the example, then there is no general way to get the size of the array that contains the element from that pointer.

In some particular cases, there may be a way to calculate the size however. For example, you could decide that certain value represents the end of the array, in which case you can iterate the successive sibling of the pointed object until you reach the terminator. This is conventionally done with character strings where the null terminator character represents end of a string.

In case you want to store a pointer to an element of an array, and want to know the size and cannot choose a value as terminator, then you would typically store the size along with the pointer.

---

> ```
> gConvexMeshVertexesArrays.push_back(convexVerts);
> ```
>
> I successfully add a pointer to an array to the vector and then try to get the size of that array.

No, you don't. You push a pointer to the first element of an array  into the vector. Then you get the size of the array element (whether you intended that or not), which you divide by the size of the element, which always results in 1.

Comment: Take a look at the 3 sample code, I successfully add a pointer to an array to the vector and then try to get the size of that array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know the size of some memory a pointer may be pointing to because pointers have no information about what data they are pointing to (except the declared type, that is).

If you want a (pointer, size) pair, take a look at `std::span` in C++20 and similar types provided in some libraries.

The well-known `sizeof(array) / sizeof(element)` expression works for arrays (and it does so at compile-time) because arrays statically know their entire size (plus they are contiguous, etc.).

Comment: You have not understood correctly. I want to get the size of the **array** that the pointer in the vector. I don't need the vector size.

Comment: @M.M Thanks, edited that out -- anyway the answer is the same.

Comment: @prostargamer See previous comment.